# How to show suggestions while entering values in input field?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a small react project, working on API calls newly. My objective is, I want to show suggestions below the input field. i mean if we enter name in input field the suggestion should show Name should not exceed 15 characters and once i enter the value the suggestion should get disappear. Can anyone please help me in this query?

Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      isName: true,
      error: ""
    };
  }

  ValidName = () => {
    const regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z])+$");
    this.setState({
      isName: regex.test(this.state.name)
    });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  hSave = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = { name: this.state.name };
    axios
      .post(`/api/Addcontact`, data, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.props.history.push("/Contact");
        } else {
          this.setState({ error: res });
          console.log(res);
        }
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form size="large">
          <Segment stacked>
            <Label className="contactLabel">*Name</Label>
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              className={`${this.state.isName ? "" : "error"} saveContact`}
              placeholder="Full Name"
              name="name"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onBlur={this.ValidName}
              value={this.state.name}
            />
            {this.state.isName ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <div className="contactError">* Invalid Name</div>
            )}

{error ? <div>{error}</div> : ""}

            <Button
              color="teal"
              className="saveContactbtn"
              onClick={this.hSave}
            >
              Save
            </Button>
          </Segment>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I'm unable to figure it out, how to show the suggestion for the input field!

Comment: What type of suggestions are you referring to?

Comment: If you have only one suggestion  like not exceed 15 characters then type it in placeholder. OR if you have more you can set label it's show after validate user input inside the handleChange  function and if it has correct value disappear that label

Comment: Do you mean showing tooltips or placeholders?

Comment: @wentjun -  like a normal tag we use for suggestion like <small>name should not exceed 15 characters</small>. Once we complete writing in the input field then it should get disappear

Comment: @Oshini - Yes Correct, but i don't have any idea how to display it

Comment: @lekhamani - no, it's like a suggestion, where i write something in the input field then it should show like "name should not exceed 15 characters". For ex: If i'm typing phone number then the suggestion should be "please include +1 and then 10 digits"

Comment: @Chandan what do you want to know the label  show and hide? I think below answer also help for you

Comment: @Oshini - The below example is using hooks concept and material ui. Is it possible to get the solution without hooks and material UI?

Comment: @Chandan There is two way <Form noValidate validated={validated}> form validation and manual label set I'll post my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. hope it will help you. but it's manual validation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AddUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName: "",
      errors: {},
    };
    this.handleUsername = this.handleUsername.bind();
    this.handleAddUser = this.handleAddUser.bind();
  }

   //UserName change event
  handleUsername(event) {
    let userName = event.target.value;
    let errors = {};
    let lastAt = userName.lastIndexOf('@');
    let lastDot = userName.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (!(lastAt < lastDot && lastAt > 0 && userName.indexOf('@@') === -1 && lastDot > 2 && (userName.length - lastDot) > 2)) {
      errors["username"] = "Your email is required and it should be valid ";
    }

    this.setState({
      userName: event.target.value,
      errors: errors,
    });
  }

  //ADD user button on click
  handleAddUser = () => {
    let formIsValid = true;
   //TODO :formIsValid needs to false when you have validation errors

    if (formIsValid) {
      //TODO :API call for submit 
    }
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="user-sidebar sidebar-nav has-header">
        <form name="addUserForm">
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-4">
              <label className="control-label" htmlFor="username">User Name: </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-8">
              <input className="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" autoFocus required value={this.state.userName} onChange={this.handleUsername} />
              <span className="error-message">{this.state.errors["username"]}</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
             <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => { this.handleAddUser(this) }}><i className="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You need a **validation** service/lib to implement your demand of:
1.show info related to the user input value
2.once input meets the condition, make it disappear (font / other css styles)

#### Implement

optional validation lib: [react-hook-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form)

sample:

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Get Started]

Comment: The example is nice and it is using hooks concept and material ui. I'll be learning hooks concept from now on. Is it possible to get the solution without hooks and material UI?

Comment: @Chandan No doubt, you can even write your custom validation service, kindly refer to my implement [here](https://github.com/ibarapascal/access-catalog/blob/master/blog/summary-of-react-develop-practice/summary-events.md/#validation) without using any libs.

Comment: @Chandan If you are not familiar with hooks, and want to use hooks and classic functions in one place, you can make a local HOC which combine those two, [sample here](https://github.com/ibarapascal/netbooks/blob/master/src/components/books/BK.tsx)